# C enum Printing error?

Tags: c, struct, enums, unions

In College we had to write a program with structs, enums and unions to display a date,
 like 1.September 2014.
I had some problems with printing an enum. I found some solutions in this forum and finally I've got no console errors anymore. But Everytime I try to run my Program it crashes.
Maybe someone of you knwos what's causing the crash:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    enum Monate{JANUAR = 1,
                FEBRUAR = 2,
                MAERZ = 3,
                APRIL = 4,
                MAI = 5,
                JUNI = 6,
                JULI = 7,
                AUGUST = 8,
                SEPTEMBER = 9,
                OKTOBER = 10,
                NOVEMBER = 11,
                DEZEMBER = 12 };

    union Monat{
        enum Monate alsMonat;
        char alsZahl;
        char alsString[10];
    };

    struct Datum {
        char tag;
        union Monat monat;
        short jahr;
    };


const char* welcherMonat(enum Monate meinMonat){
    switch(meinMonat){
            case JANUAR: return"Januar";
            break;

            case FEBRUAR: return"Februar";
            break;

            case MAERZ: return"Maerz";
            break;

            case APRIL: return"April";
            break;

            case MAI: return"Mai";
            break;

            case JUNI: return"Juni";
            break;

            case JULI: return"Juli";
            break;

            case AUGUST: return"August";
            break;

            case SEPTEMBER: return"September";
            break;

            case OKTOBER: return"Oktober";
            break;

            case NOVEMBER: return"November";
            break;

            case DEZEMBER: return"Dezember";
            break;
        }
}

void ausgabe(struct Datum *datum){
    char month[10]=" ";
    printf("Tag: %c\n",(*datum).tag);

    enum Monate monat2=(*datum).monat.alsMonat;
    printf("Monat: %s\n",welcherMonat(monat2));
    printf("Jahr: %d\n\n",(*datum).jahr);

}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    struct Datum Geburtstag = {'3',AUGUST,1995};
    struct Datum Heute = {'3','12',2014};
    struct Datum Millenium = {'1',1,2000};

        ausgabe(&Geburtstag);
        ausgabe(&Heute);
        ausgabe(&Millenium);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side notes: 1. you don't need to `break` after `return`, 2. `(*foo).bar` is better written as `foo->bar`

Comment: Also, run your program in a debugger to find out on which line it crashes on.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: `'12'`, a multi-byte character literal, does not match any of the enum tags in your `welcherMonat()` function, which results in the function returning a garbage value that `printf()` gets a little grumpy about...

Comment: Use english in code before asking for help in a english help env.

Answer (score 1):

Use GDB.  It is the Gnu DeBugger.  Compile your code with the `-g` option enabled, and it will include all of the proper debugging symbols.  You can then use GDB to put a manual break in the program and step through it one line at a time, look at variables, and see exactly where it is crashing.

Comment: why thank you.  It is nice to know that someone else out there appreciates the power of GDB.  i think my "about me" section says something about it.

Comment: it just that half the people who post questions seem to have no idea how to debug things. Also school dont seem to teach it

Answer (score 0):

How can you have a multi-character char like this:

```
struct Datum Heute = {'3','12',2014};
```

Doesn't your compiler throw a warning for this? It should ideally

Comment: `'12'` is legal, but its value is implementation-defined. It's a nearly useless language feature.

Comment: @KeithThompson My compiler throws an error for this and also we see a union being initialized by just a char constant which is not right?

Comment: And that is where it fails, but `struct Datum Heute = {'3',12,2014};` works. But the function does not catch everything (no `default`) and that was the warning my compiler issued.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry not an error a warning `warning: multi-character character constant`

Comment: Visual C: *warning C4715: 'welcherMonat' : not all control paths return a value*

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I overlooked the MultiCharacter warning...
When I choose a one-character month it still freezes at the second print, when I want to print the date by using a char as month. The other two types of printing the month(by enum) work totally fine.
Our task was to print three different dates by using all three kinds of month-printing.

I think I know the Problem:

```
enum Monate monat2=(*datum).monat.alsMonat;
printf("Monat: %s\n",welcherMonat(monat2));
```

when I give the function a char instead of an enum, "monat2" is empty.
But how could I check whether I give him a char or an enum?